# Google App Engine - uploading files, best practices

Tags: google-app-engine, file-upload

I want to upload files into my [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) project.

I've been reading a while on this issue, and there is a lot of answers arguing Blobstore is the best option.

But if I did understand this well, these are database objects. I would like to upload them as system files to a caching theme or to ease a possible future migration to another [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

**Imagine I want to save several files for each user, a couple of images, text files, maybe some video, etc...
If some day I want to move these static files to another CDN, shouldn't it be out of the database?**

Is that a good idea? Is there a solution?

Comment: are you talking about just some static files along with your project, or are you talking about a part of your app that requires users to upload their own files? Are they images or some other file type? Do you need to programatically access these files from your application code?

Comment: I included more information above, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use GAE datastore to store the files references (for example, video, images, etc.) and upload the content on [Amazon S3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3). You may even allow the clients to upload the content directly to Amazon S3 without to process the content through GAE using Amazon HTML POST Forms (*[Browser Uploads to S3 using HTML POST Forms](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1)*). [Amazon AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) also offers CDN ([CloudFront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_CloudFront)) with tight integration with S3 service.

If you need to store only small pictures, you may also consider the Google images services as it offers "free" CDN and some cool out-of the box transformations.

Comment: That is one of my thoughts, but I would like a free-of-charge option, to start :)

Comment: Yes, I'll use GAE database (BLOBStore) for now :)

Comment: Although it would be great to have the size of the file to upload before uploading it...

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to the filesystem on App Engine, so your options are to store data to the datastore, or the blobstore. Of the two, the blobstore is generally the better choice for storing file uploads.

Regarding porting to a CDN, no matter how you do this it's going to require changes. App Engine is not a CDN, no two CDNs are exactly alike, and it's unlikely the CDN would expose an interface that you can interact with using standard filesystem operations anyway.